# FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, symfony, fatal-error

I have developed a Symfony2 project 
Parse error is the following :

> FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting
>   T_FUNCTION in
>   C:\wamp\www\TPSForm\src\Dwm\CatalogueBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
>   line 57

Can anyone point me in the right direction to clear up this issue.

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}")
 * @Template()
 */
 public function indexAction($name)
 {
    return array('name' => $name);
 }
 /**
 * @Route("/addCategorie/{nomCat}")
 * @Template()
 */
 public function addCatAction($nomCat)
 {
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $cat=new Categorie();
    $cat->setNomCategorie($nomCat);
    $em->persist($cat);
    $em->flush();
    return array('cat' => $cat);
 }
 /**
 * @Route("/newProduit")
 * @Template()
 */
 public function newProduitAction(Request $request)
 {
    $p=new Produit();
    $form=$this->createFormBuilder($p)
        ->add("nomProduit","text")
        ->add("prix","text")
        ->add("categorie","entity",array(
            "class"=>"Dwm\CatalogueBundle\Entity\Categorie",
            "property"=>"nomCategorie"
            ))
        ->add("Add","submit")
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid()){
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($p);
        $em->flush();
    return array('f' => $form->createView());
    }
   }
```

Comment: I think you are missing the closing bracket for your class

Comment: Please include any attempts to fix the problem you have tried yourself, this can help people identify the error a little easier. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you didn't close your class... is it the full file ? add a closing `}` at the end

Comment: Yeah, that's true it seems that i forget to close them

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes when you didn't close any opening braces.

Check and see whether all the opening braces are closed properly or not.